# Can´t save in a "to_csv" with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have been trying to sabe some usersnames and passwords at the end of my code with the "to_csv" but it doesn´t save anything at all. The console does not show any message or output file at all. Can´t find whtas the problem.

```
def registrar():
    df = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\Usuario\Documents\David\Programación\usuarios_ayp.csv", encoding='cp1252')
    
    decision = input('Bienvenido. Ya eres usuario? (si/no)')
    
    if decision.lower() == 'si' :
        usuarionuevo = validar()
        if usuarionuevo != '':
            return usuarionuevo
        else:
            opcion = input('Quieres registrarte r o cualuier otra letr para salir')
            if opcion.lower == 'r':
                registrar()     #llamado recursivo
            else:
                return ''
    else:
        usuarionuevo = input('Ingresa un nombre de usuario: ')
        contranuevo = input('Ingresa una contraseña: ')
        
        buscar = df['Usuarios']
        
        while True:
            if usuarionuevo in buscar.unique():
                print('Usuario existente')
                usuarionuevo = input('Ingresa un nombre de usuario: ')
                
            else:
                dic = {'Usuarios': usuarionuevo, 'Contrasenas': contranuevo}
                serie = pd.Series(dic)
                df.append(serie, ignore_index = True)
                df.to_csv(r"C:\Users\Usuario\Documents\David\Programación\usuarios_ayp.csv",
                          index = False)
registrar()
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not getting any message because you missed a break and are entering an infinity loop in your last else condition. Thats why you should always avoid using while true loops.

And also you need to reassign `df` in order to write it to the csv file.

Change your else for this and should work fine:

```py
    else:
        usuarionuevo = input('Ingresa un nombre de usuario: ')
        contranuevo = input('Ingresa una contraseña: ')

        buscar = df['Usuarios']

        while usuarionuevo in buscar.unique():
            print('Usuario existente')
            usuarionuevo = input('Ingresa un nombre de usuario: ')

        else:
            dic = {'Usuarios': usuarionuevo, 'Contrasenas': contranuevo}
            serie = pd.Series(dic)
            df = df.append(serie, ignore_index=True)
            df.to_csv(r"usuarios_ayp.csv",
                      index=False)
```